# Tabs with Icons using ViewPager, How to layout them? by Attaching Some Layout File

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I am new to Android, Designing an Android Application that contains "Tabs".
I have designed this:

[image]

But I want to design like this,

[image]

I think there must be way, as like of populating lists using Custom Adapters, But I am not finding any thing to do this, the tutorials that are available on Android Web are out of scope of my mind, because I am new..

My code:

Tabs.xml

Tabs.java

```
    package com.example.medbleep;

    import TabsManager.TabPagerAdapter;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Tabs extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        private ViewPager viewPager;
        private TabPagerAdapter mAdapter;
        private android.app.ActionBar actionBar;

        private int numberOfTabs = 5;
        // Tab titles
        private int[] tabIcons = {R.drawable.home,R.drawable.home,R.drawable.home,R.drawable.home,R.drawable.home,R.drawable.home};
        private String[] tabText = { "Home", "units", "conferences", "couses", "more" };
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.tabs);

            imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tab_icon);
            textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tab_title);

            // Initialization
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            viewPager.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkLoginBlue));
            actionBar = getActionBar();
            mAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                    numberOfTabs);

            viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            // Adding Tabs
            for (int i = 0; i<5 ; i++) {

                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabText[i])
                        .setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(tabIcons[i]))
                        .setTabListener(this));

                //actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.tab_layout).setText(tabText[i]).setIcon(tabIcons[i]).setTabListener(this));
                //actionBar.setLogo(tabIcons[4]);

                //actionBar.setIcon(tabIcons[i]);
                //actionBar.setTitle(tabText[i]);
            }


            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // on changing the page
                    // make respected tab selected
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // on tab selected
            // show respected fragment view
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
```

TabPagerAdapter.java

```
package TabsManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                HomeTabFragment homeTabFragment = new HomeTabFragment();
                return homeTabFragment;
            case 1:
                UnitTabFragment unitTabFragment = new UnitTabFragment();
                return unitTabFragment;
            case 2:
                ConferencesTabFragment conferencesTabFragment = new ConferencesTabFragment();
                return conferencesTabFragment;
            case 3: 
                CoursesTabFragment coursesTabFragment = new CoursesTabFragment();
                return coursesTabFragment;
            case 4:
                MoreTabFragment moreTabFragment = new MoreTabFragment();
                return moreTabFragment;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }




}
```

Comment: refer [this tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout#add-icons-to-tablayout) for tabs with icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making this, your have to create Custom Adaptor and set width and height According to your requirement of each tab.
Please Follow this:
http://mobikul.com/make-custom-tabs-icons-android/